# Why my sessions variables have been automatically unset when i redirect to then same script?

Tags: php

I have set a session variable in testmysql.php named foo  and i redirect the script to them same script again where I print the session var and then unset it .. However, the session var seems to have been unset already when I have redirected ..Why is this and how do i sort this out ?

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(empty($_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    header("location:testmysql.php?redirect". '=' . 'bar');
}

var_dump( $_SESSION);
unset ($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Comment: The Location HTTP header takes absolute URIs only, not relative ones. Don't depend on browser error recovery.

Answer (score 1):

You are not aborting the script when you set a redirection, thus `unset ($_SESSION['foo'])` is always executed:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(empty($_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    header("location:testmysql.php?redirect". '=' . 'bar');
    exit; // <--- Missing
}

var_dump( $_SESSION);
unset ($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if` with `if else`

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    header("location:testmysql.php?redirect". '=' . 'bar');
}
else
{
    var_dump( $_SESSION);
    unset ($_SESSION['foo']);
}
```